# How to get list of Templates via Anguilla framework?

Tags: cme

How to retrieve the list of all the Templates in the Tridion CMS via GUI Anguilla code?

How to use the `$models.getItem($const.TCMROOT)` exactly?

Comment: When you say "all the templates" do you really mean that? All Component Templates, Page Templates, Template Building Blocks, etc. in all Folders within all Publications? Or do you have something more modest in mind, like all of the Component Templates that work for a given Schema?